# ListView cloning removes the default font functionality

Tags: c#, listview, listviewitem

I have a basic `ListView` with a few columns.

I create a `ListViewItem` using:

```
ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem();
item.Text = "First";
item.SubItems[1].Text = "Second";
```

Then I add the `ListViewItem` to my `ListView`

```
ListView1.Items.Add(item);
```

So, I have a method where I change the `Font` of the `ListView1`, 
and if the `ListView` changes the font, all `ListViewItem-s` do as well.

But if I use the `.Clone()` function

```
ListView1.Items.Add((ListViewItem)item.Clone());
```

It clones the `ListViewItem` and it hard codes the `Font`.

So changing the `ListView` font won't change the `ListViewItem-s` font.

```
ListView1.Font = new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 15F, FontStyle.Regular);
```

Comment: You should change the font of the `ListView` before `Clone` a `ListViewItem` so the new item inherits the new font.

Comment: @JQSOFT the problem is, the user changes to font of the ListView AFTER the cloning. Basicly, i want to keep the ListViewItems font linked to the ListView's font. But cloning them makes them have their own hardcoded font for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just `Dispose` the current `Font` of the `ListView` before setting a new one:

```cs
ListView1.Font.Dispose();
ListView1.Font = new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 15F, FontStyle.Regular);
```

This way, the `ListViewItem-s` including the cloned ones will be forced to inherit the new font of the `ListView` control.

[image: SOQ59950483]

Comment: Edit using this method has like a 2% change of crashing for some reason, reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60506530/resetting-listview-font-causes-random-crashes

Comment: @thekguy Read Hans Passant's comment there.