# Resetting listview font causes random crashes

Tags: c#, listview

In reference from:
[Main Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59950483/listview-cloning-removes-the-default-font-functionality/59966892?noredirect=1#comment106119724_59966892)

I have the code where i reset the font using:

```
ListView1.Font.Dispose();
ListView1.Font = new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 15F, FontStyle.Regular);
```

Altough for some reason, at random it gives this error (so not all the time).

```
System.ArgumentException: Invalid parameter.
   at System.Drawing.Font.ToLogFont(Object logFont, Graphics graphics)
   at System.Drawing.Font.ToLogFont(Object logFont)
   at System.Drawing.Font.ToHfont()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.FontHandleWrapper..ctor(Font font)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.get_FontHandle()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.SetWindowFont()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnHandleCreated(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ListView.OnHandleCreated(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmCreate(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ListView.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

My program does the following,
Clone lisviews to other listviews etc, so thats why i need to reset the font. Because if i dont it will force all fonts on ListViewItems, altough in about 2% of the tries it crashes with the above error. Quite confusing.

Comment: Don't `Dispose` `ListView1.Font`: it's `ListView1` that *owns* the `Font` so let it `Dispose` it when required. https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Control.cs,31090a07bae84945 Note `DisposeFontHandle();` within the `set`

Comment: I have to Dispose the font, because it will reset the static font set in the ListViewItems when it resizes. When i clone listviewitems it has a hardcoded font, and i need to dispose that font in order for it to re-link (when ListView1.Font changes the ListViewItems change, that only occurs when i dispose the font after cloning).

Comment: I basicly want to achieve cloning listviewitems without it hardcoding the current font since i want to change all fonts by setting ListView1.Font

Comment: The call stack is quite unrelated to the code snippet.  The usual reason for "invalid parameter" is a resource leak, too many active drawing objects.  Use Task Manager, Processes tab and add columns for "GDI Objects" and "USER Objects".  More than a couple of hundred of these is a problem.

Comment: The error only occurs when using that code. I tested this out multiple times.

Comment: @HansPassant GDI Objects and User Objects are at 100-130 and dont really exceed it over time. Crashes occur random and the Gdi/User objects arent more when it happens.

Comment: @HansPassant Foreachign the Listview, and changing all Fonts per ListViewItem seperately does work without crashing, but is quite a bad practice to be honest.